# Read data from a register in C-code

Tags: c, spi, register, read

I am a beginner and learning by myself.
I need your help to start the third implementation in my life in VIVADO ( "Hello world" and "led")

I will implement SPI connection with DMA, but because I am a beginner I would like to start with the simplest : read data from register.

I have "briefly " read ZYNQ technical reference and found on p 785 and 1719 or "SPI Controller (SPI)". I think I need it for my implementation.

```
#define SPI_Controller_Addr     0xE0007020 // Serial Peripheral Interface
```

In VHDL if I implement a process of reading data, I would do it like this:

```
data_output <= register_data(to_integer(unsigned(address_port)));
```

**My questions**:

1. Do I need "xspi.h"( SPI device driver ) to implement reading data from register? The instance of the SPI device (`static XSpi SpiInstance`)?
2. Do I need to initialize the SPI driver? GPIO driver?
3. Does anyone have a simple example how  to read data from register in C?

Thank you in advance for all your recommendation and information?

Comment: You should not "briefly" read the documentation. Study it carefully. Have you used C with microcontrollers before?

Comment: If you want to find simple example try googling something like this: "microcontroller_name SPI application note" It always works like a charm with NXP MCUS

Comment: Your questions are (particularly item 3) about fundamentals of C programming. Reading from a register is one of the first things you should learn when doing embedded C.

Comment: All the 3 questions you have posted here are more like tool specific,  and hence you will get better response in xilinx forum.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have used C, but I have no experience with microcontrollers before

Comment: Vivado (or any other FPGA) is not something you can *glance* the documentation at. Set aside probably one week to at least skim *all* the user manual

Comment: Regarding 3) please check out [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer 1: Here we are talking about memory-mapped registers. IO-mapped registers are a different issue.*

*Disclaimer 2: I have no idea about the specific MCU you are using. This answer is a more general one.*

You can look at "registers" as a special kind of a static variable. You should think of it as `volatile` in most cases, and sometimes as read-only or write-only (`const` in the former case is a good thing).

Accessing a register may trigger some reaction in the connected hardware. For example, writing to the (write-only) buffer register of a UART triggers the start of the transmission, if prerequisites are taken.

If the linker can resolve the addresses of registers, for example by a linker script, you only need an `extern` declaration of it.

In many cases the register's address is coded as a number and needs to be converted into an address. Your example:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define SPI_Controller_Addr 0xE0007020u

void set_register(uint32_t value) {
    uint32_t* addr = (uint32_t*)SPI_Controller_Addr;
    *addr = value;
}

uint32_t get_register(void) {
    uint32_t* addr = (uint32_t*)SPI_Controller_Addr;
    return *addr;
}
```

> Do I need "xspi.h"( SPI device driver ) to implement reading data from register? The instance of the SPI device (static XSpi SpiInstance)?

Header files generally ease your development. Commonly they are accompanied with documentation that includes examples.

Header files "just" declare stuff (macros, variables, functions) for you to use.

In a strict sense, you don't need it. You can write all necessary declarations and definitions yourself.

> Do I need to initialize the SPI driver? GPIO driver?

That depends heavily on your target system. If it has a driver (a software component that helps you to access hardware), use it. Most probably you will need to initialize it.

Again, such drivers are accompanied with documentation. Please read it.

> Does anyone have a simple example how to read data from register in C?

Done, above.

**Edit:**

*What do these functions do?*

Their name is straight forward and tell you what they do:

- `set_register()` sets (writes) the register with the given value.
- `get_register()` gets (reads) the register's value and returns it.

It is most common to use an imperative verb as first part of the functions' names, and "set" and "get" are in wide use for such access functions.

*How to use these functions?*

Well, `set_register()` will be called if you want to set the register. At the caller site you provide the value to set, for example `0x12345678` (unsigned):

```c
    set_register(0x12345678u);
```

On the other hand, if you want to read the register and, let's say, store it in a variable `x`, you call `get_register()`:

```c
    uint32_t x;
    x = get_register();
```

Comment: Dear the busybee! Thank zou for taking time to reply. I have some question regarding to your example. 1. Could you please provide an explanation of it? 2. What is addr in set_register? address of a register which read( received) data? 3. What does  *addr mean? dereference ? 4.

Comment: 1. What specifically do you mean? -- 2. `addr` is the local variable that holds the address of the register to be _written_. -- 3. In a simple language: The star operator means "dereference" in an expression. In a variable declaration it means "pointer". Please consult your beginner's C book. -- 4. (Intentionally left blank.) Oh, BTW, German keyboard?

Comment: 1. it is difficult to understand for me as a beginner what these twp function do... Could you provide a simple example ?

Comment: Not a good idea to use hex constants without `u` suffix. They may end up as type `int`, `unsigned int` or `long`, thanks to the dangerous integer constant rules in C. I explain this further here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290) Also, as mentioned in that link, accessing a hardware register without `volatile` qualifiers is always a bug. All your `(uint32_t*)SPI_Controller_Addr` lines have this bug.